# Basic Bash for loop one-liner fails but doesn't exit and produces no output

Tags: linux, bash

I have a long list of locations in a file called `file-locations` which have the following format:

```
/mnt/q/fire/210407_NB552563_0007*/analysis/annotation/FIRID-5382*/*.gff
```

I've tried the following one liner to copy them to my current location:

```
for i in `cat file-locations`; do cp $i .; done
```

But this fails to do anything. It just 'runs' forever and won't exit without ctrl+C.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: First step is usually to set up execution tracing, so use `set -x`. This is probably data dependent. Maybe there is `/dev/stdin` as one of your filenames?

Comment: Try changing your `cp` command to `echo cp` to see where it is stalling. Are any of the files huge and are the two locations on the same physical system?

Comment: Why do you need a `for` loop that's going to call `cp` for each file? Why not just `cp mnt/q/fire/210407_NB552563_0007*/analysis/annotation/FIRID-5382*/*.gff .` ?

Comment: @JeremyMeadows, an unquoted command substitution like that will expand globs. As would that unquoted expansion of `$i`.

Comment: @ilkkachu Huh, I tested it on my machine and got `cp: cannot stat '/home/jeremy/foo*': No such file or directory`, when it contained `foobar` and `foobaz`. Not sure what that's about then... edit: jk, I spelt my name own name wrong and it broke. sorry

Comment: Luke, please provide a sample of your `file-locations` file. We're trying to understand whether the lines match the glob (pattern) format you've shown, or whether the lines really do contain globs (patterns) like the single line you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

If your file locations match the glob you've given us, just use that glob to match the set of files:

```
cp -v /mnt/q/fire/210407_NB552563_0007*/analysis/annotation/FIRID-5382*/*.gff .
```

No need for a loop, and certainly not a file of paths, *unless* your set of files is actually a disjoint set from those files matched by the glob pattern.

If you really do need to read the list of files, you need to assume that none of the file names have an embedded newline in them (`touch $'surprise\nname'`), and then you can read filenames as one per line,

```
while IFS= read -r filename
do
    cp -v "$filename" .
done <file-locations
```

Replace the `cp` command in this loop with these two lines if you want control of the logging output format,

```
    printf "Copying %s: " "$filename" >&2
    cp "$filename" . && echo ok >&2
```

Comment: The lines have globs, don't they remain with literal `*` with `cp "$filename"`?

Comment: Where in the question does it say the lines have globs? I didn't interpret it that way at all

Comment: At the beginning. `a long list of locations in a file called file-locations which have the following format: /mnt/q/fire/210407_NB552563_0007*/analysis/annotation/FIRID-5382*/*.gff`

Comment: @thanasisp I read that sentence to mean the locations have a format matching that glob. So a line might be `/mnt/q/fire/210407_NB552563_000799/analysis/annotation/FIRID-538288/77.gff`

Comment: Yes, this is a possible interprentation. Another one is that it's literal. I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your responses. I've learned a lot from reading them.

The solution itself is embarrassingly simple and lies in the fact that the locations were on NAS which (as it turns out) is running slowly, despite the files being only ~3mb.

I initially tried changing 'cp' to 'echo' to see how the globs worked following your suggestions:

```
for i in `cat file-locations`; do echo $i .; done
```

This also failed. So I then tried it on a random file with the format:

```
Help /
I /
Need/
Somebody/
```

Which worked perfectly showing that the one-liner made logical sense. Then I just added one file location in. It took around 20 seconds but the file copied. I then added in the remaining 30 or so files. It looked like it was doing nothing but after 20 minutes (insanely long) the files had all been copied successfully.

Thank you all again for your input :)